# Is it okay to change UI in the OnActivated event on iPhone in CocoaTouch?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios

Is one allowed to change/setup the UI in the applications `OnActivated` event?
It seems like I get sometimes incorrect screen setups and wonder if it is actually allowed what I'm doing.

Comment: Print the current thread ID to the console in OnActivated and then call InvokeOnMainThread and do the same.  If they are equal, then it should be fine.  I would think that OnActivated would be on the main UI thread, but it doesn't hurt to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apple documentation states, "If your application was previously in the background, you could also use it [applicationDidBecomeActive] to refresh your application’s user interface."